# How to change the color theme of the integrated terminal in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, git-bash

This [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/a-more-integrated-terminal-experience/) presents the way to work with an integrated terminal in Visual Studio. Does anyone know however if there is a possibility to have different theme background on the terminal (let's say Dark) than the one you use in the main coding area of the editor (let's say Blue)? I am primarily interested in working with Git Bash which I have set up like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025108/integrating-git-bash-with-visual-studio) (last answer). Thanks.